# XPath 2.0 Leading '/' cannot select the root node of the tree containing the context item: the context item is not a node

Tags: saxon, xpath-2.0

Trying to check that one value (once tokenized) doesn't match another value in my document:

```
/foo/bar/baz/tokenize(value,',')[not(. =(/foo/biz/value/string(),'bing'))]
```

Specifically here, checking that /foo/bar/baz/value (which is 'ding,dong,bing') doesn't match /foo/biz/value/string() or the value 'bong'.

But I'm getting "Leading '/' cannot select the root node of the tree containing the context item: the context item is not a node"

Is there any way that I can do this in XPath, or do I need to get out into XQuery and start to worry about variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're using Saxon, you can take advantage of the fact that XPath 3.0 allows you to bind variables:

```
let $foo := /foo return $foo/bar/baz/tokenize(value,',')
    [not(. =($foo/biz/value/string(),'bing'))]
```

or you could pull the expression out of the predicate:

```
let $exceptions := (/foo/biz/value/string(),'bing') 
return /foo/bar/baz/tokenize(value,',')[not(. = $exceptions)]
```

If you want pure XPath 2.0 you can achieve the same with an ugly "for" binding:

```
for $foo in /foo return $foo/bar/baz/tokenize(value,',')
   [not(. =($foo/biz/value/string(),'bing'))]
```

If you're in XSLT, of course, you can use `current()`.

Comment: #Legend. Thanks @Michael.